# Repeated regex delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I am using this code, which I picked up from the 'net somewhere, to split a line of text into "words":

```
def SplitStringIntoWords(inputString, delimiters=' \t,'):
    words = re.split('[' + delimiters + ']', inputString.strip())
    return len(words), words
```

However, I just noticed that it is not behaving well with multiple internal spaces (or tabs).

```
    numWords, words = SplitStringIntoWords('A B')
    print(str(numWords) + ' words')
    print(*words, sep=' ')

    numWords, words = SplitStringIntoWords('A  B')
    print(str(numWords) + ' words')
    print(*words, sep=' ')

    numWords, words = SplitStringIntoWords('A   B')
    print(str(numWords) + ' words')
    print(*words, sep=' ')
```

gives

> 2 words
> A B
>
> 3 words
> A  B
>
> 4 words
> A   B

What's the best way to collapse multiple delimiters (spaces in this case) which are internal to the string?

I really only want to do it for the first X "words", as everything beyond word 5 is free format text, where I suppose I ought not to collapse multiple spaces.  But that would be "nice to have", not "must have".

Comment: Append a `+` sign to `'[' + delimiters + ']'` => `'[' + delimiters + ']+'`

Comment: You could use `[delimiters]+` to match 1 or more along with [`maxsplit` for `re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

Comment: Please turn on your browser's spell-check feature.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just doing `"A  B".split()`, which automatically collapses adjacent delimiters for you?

Comment: This a simplified example. I want to parse a trace log, line by line, which is "somewhat" structured"

Comment: No, if you take a look again @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Show me the code... I don't think `delimiters=' \t,'` presents only white spaces. There is a [comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma) @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @revo: Agh, dammit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding a `+` to `'[' + delimiters + ']'`, you should be able to get what you want.

```
def SplitStringIntoWords(inputString, delimiters=' \t,'):
    words = re.split('[' + delimiters + ']+', inputString.strip())
    return len(words), words
```